# Xamarin.Forms - Embedded resource causing - The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: xamarin.forms, font-awesome

Implemented FontImageSource to display icons on my app by following [this](https://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20201113-UsingFontAwesomeInXamarinForms.html), icons show up, but embedded file - FontAwesome.otf causing `"Skipped 3120 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread"` issue and app is not navigating to other pages. After removing the file app work normal again. I am using **Font Awesome Solid** `.otf` file which is around 500KB, regular (free) does not have all icons I need (it is 95KB), it work fine with **Regular icons**. Is there a way to fix it? I need to use those icons.

**UPDATE:**

Steps:

1. Added Font Awesome Solid .otf file to Resources folder. Downloaded it from [here](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-desktop/setup/getting-started).
   [image]
2. Added `[assembly: ExportFont("FontAwesome.otf", Alias = "FontAwesome")]` to App.xaml.cs before namespace.
3. Created `FontAwesomeIcons.cs`, got it from [here](https://github.com/DamirsCorner/20201113-xamarin-font-awesome/blob/master/FontAwesome/FontAwesome/FontAwesomeIcons.cs)
4. Added `xmlns:fontAwesome="clr-namespace:MobileApp.UI"` code .xaml pages.
5. Created icons:

```
<Image>
          <Image.Source>
                  <FontImageSource FontFamily="FontAwesome" Color="#666666" Size="Large" Glyph="{x:Static fontAwesome:FontAwesomeIcons.CloudUpload}"/>
          </Image.Source>
    </Image>
```

Main page loads  - icons are there, I click a button to navigate to another page and it takes a lot of time to do API call, I get a result and then App does not go to next page and code does not go to next line. Removing .otf file solves the issue but I need to use icons. Any advice?

Comment: 1) Please add your code to the question. Even if its exactly the same as the linked code, this confirms that there isn't some subtle detail that is different. And will help others in the future who google for this topic (links can get broken over time). 2) Does text rendered with the font look okay? (This confirms that it is loaded okay, just takes too long, and leaves app in a bad state.)

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

The blog post linked by question contains a link to a github repository. I've [cloned 20201113-xamarin-font-awesome](https://github.com/ToolmakerSteve/20201113-xamarin-font-awesome), updated it to Xamarin Forms 5.0.0.2291 and Android API 31.

Runs without problem. Note that when running on emulator, its common to have skipped frames at the start.

What's important is whether the UI is still alive. I verified this with a button that brings up an alert.

xaml on a content page:

```
<ContentPage ...
    xmlns:fontAwesome="clr-namespace:FontAwesome"
    ...>

    <StackLayout Margin="20">
        <Image>
            <Image.Source>
                <FontImageSource FontFamily="FontAwesome5Regular"
                                 Color="Black"
                                 Glyph="{x:Static fontAwesome:FontAwesomeIcons.ThumbsUp}"/>
            </Image.Source>
        </Image>
        <Button Text="Press Me" Clicked="Button_Clicked" />
    </StackLayout>
...
```

.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Testing", "Yes, the UI is still alive.", "OK");
        });
    }
}
```

FontAwesomeIcons.cs:

```
using System;

namespace FontAwesome
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The unicode values for all FontAwesome icons.
    /// <para/>
    /// See https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet
    /// <para/>
    /// This code was automatically generated by FA2CS (https://github.com/matthewrdev/fa2cs).
    /// </summary>
    public static partial class FontAwesomeIcons
    {
        //...
    
        /// <summary>
        /// fa-thumbs-up unicode value ("\uf164").
        /// <para/>
        /// This icon supports the following styles: Light (Pro), Regular, Solid, Duotone (Pro)
        /// <para/>
        /// See https://fontawesome.com/icons/thumbs-up
        /// </summary>
        public const string ThumbsUp = "\uf164";
        
        //...
    }
}
```

`FontAwesome5Regular.otf` is in main project, folder Resources / Fonts.
Build Action = Embedded resource.

Result:

### [image]

Download this repo. See if it works for you. If it does, then look for differences between it, and what you did.

Comment: I see icons when main page loads, App work file with FontAwesomeRegulat.otf file which is 95KB, I am using FontAwesomeSolid.otf which is 500KB and when I try to navigate to another page, after getting result from API call, I check if `IsSuccessStatusCode` , it does not go to next line after that.